# How to put an SSRS built in variable into SQL variable

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services

Building a report in SSRS 2008.  I need to capture the built-in User!UserId variable so I can use it in my dataset query.  It is part of my report security.  I have tried a couple ways, but niether worked:

```
DECLARE @currentUser varchar(30) =User!UserID
```

and inline:

```
SELECT @retVal = COUNT(*)
FROM MySecurityTable
WHERE ExpirationTime > GETDATE() AND UserName =User!UserId
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a Hidden report parameter @UserID and set its default value as `=User!UserID`.

Use the parameter @UserID in your dataset.

```
SELECT @retVal = COUNT(*)
FROM MySecurityTable
WHERE ExpirationTime > GETDATE() AND UserName = @UserID
```